# `react/no-this-in-sfc` when `this` does not refer to the SFC

Tags: jquery, reactjs, eslint

```js
  const handleTweets = () => {
    $('.embed-tool__content--twitter').each(function () {

      // eslint-disable-next-line
      this.contentWindow.postMessage(
        {
          element: $(this).attr('id'),
          query: 'height'
        },
        'https://twitframe.com'
      );
    });
  };
```

I have this code inside a functional component. On removing `eslint-disable-next-line`, I am getting this error in ESLint:

```
Stateless functional components should not use `this`  react/no-this-in-sfc
```

Clearly, in my code, `this` refers to the `HTMLElement` binded to the (anonymous) function by JQuery, and not the SFC itself. Then why am I getting this error? Moreover, why in the next line, `$(this)` isn't throwing any error?

PS: I know I can directly use `this.id`. `$(this).attr` is just to provide MRE.

Comment: I just got the same problem while defining a class in my SFC, and using "this" in the methods of the class. Seems like this eslint rule is a bit too aggressive. Did you find a solution / workaround so far?